# how to add div2 to div1 right side bottom in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, sass, less

how to added div2 to div1 right side bottom?

[image]

Comment: you can use flexbox

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For positioning elements like that, I'd recommend to use `position` property. And for responsiveness, you can use `media queries`. Make first div, as `relative` so that, second div gets positioned according to it, as `absolute` positioned elements gets positioned according to the closest positioned ancestor element.

PS: Let know in case you got a question :)

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you give more details on how you're trying to display this?

Anyway Here's a quick example :

```
.container {
padding: 20px;
}


#div1 {
  padding: 20px;
  width:60%;
  background:blue;
  float: left;
}

#div2 {
  width:40%;
  padding: 20px;
  background:red;
  float: right;
}
```

html:

```
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="green">Float Column 1</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque aliquid aspernatur sequi, perferendis beatae minus hic impedit, velit et dicta. Consequatur rem ipsum neque delectus eveniet sapiente ex quis quam.
  </div>
  
  <div id=div2>
    <div class="blue">Float Column 2</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio iure doloribus, fugiat eum blanditiis ipsam qui obcaecati facilis voluptatem minima, iste deserunt illum nobis aliquam. Assumenda totam aspernatur, et minima!
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to use absolute positioning.

if you html is

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

you need this css

```
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
}

div2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%
  height: 200px
}
```

if tou html is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

tou need this css

```
.container {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.div1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%
  height: 200px
}
```

at first sample I paying attention that div2 positioning absolute to div1, but at second sample div2 positioning absolute to container, also you need set width: fit-content to container for it will have div1 width

Comment: Hey there, the code you have posted will align the div2 at bottom line, but will place it inside div1, and not out of it. Take a look at my code :)